# Keep getting "Modules has no default exports"

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript file (in `modules/firebase.ts`) with this as its contents:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

// Configure Firestore
admin.initializeApp();

export = {
  admin,
  db: admin.firestore(),
  rtdb: admin.database(),
  functions
};
```

Now I want to import that into a different typescript file. When I do `import firebase from "./modules/firebase"` It says the module at `"..../modules/firebase"` has no default exports. How do I fix this?

It also won't let me do `import admin from "firebase-admin";`, I always have to use the `*`.

Comment: You're exporting everything as `named` exports, so you either need to use `import * as firebase from './firebase'` again or call each export by its name: `import { admin } from './firebase'`